# ui.router not being loaded/executed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to ui.router and trying to get it working on a new application. The code is behaving like the state provider is either not loaded or it does not see the ui-view DOM element. I know the dependency is loaded properly (or least it isn't throwing any errors) and I have been over a ton of blog posts but everything looks right. I have a couple 'made it here' style messages but I never see them in the console.

> > The plunk below shows the following paragraph is not an issue. I am leaving the paragraph here for posterity but do not see a strike-through option in SO formatting...
> >
> > > I should also point out that this will be a SharePoint provider hosted app so there is a ton of query string garbage that I suspect is mucking things up. Unfortunately I can't get rid of them.

---Edit---

[I made a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZpGutgMT1UpbosgluNHc?p=preview)

/---Edit---

Here is my module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']).
    config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/admin.html',
            onEnter: function ($stateParams) {
                console.log("Entered Admin route");
            }
            //controller: 'myController'
        })
        .state('sitebinding', {
            url: '/sitebinding',
            templateUrl: 'sitebinding.html'
        })
        .state('scrum', {
            url: '/scrum',
            templateUrl: 'scrum.html'
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }
]);

angular.module('myApp',[
    'myApp.controllers'
]);
```

Here is the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.models = {
        helloAngular: 'I work!'
    };

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log('In state change start');
    })
});
```

And here is the relevant bits from the index.cshtml.

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div ui-view="app"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but you've got what they call a "named route" in the HTML but you don't use named routes in your `$stateProvider` configuration. Have you tried changing `ui-view="app"` to just `ui-view=""`?

Comment: Yes, I added the "app" while trying to get it to work. I have tied both ui-view and ui-view="".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your trying to do here in your plunkr. You have `scrum.html` in your route setup but it does not exist in your file tree. Are you just trying to get `admin.html` to show? Are you trying to fire this view on a click?

Comment: Yes, sorry, clipboard inheritance. I am just trying to get the first (default) route to work.